# Datamapper breaks app when saving urls

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I'm making a URL shortener application in Sinatra. It works as follows:

The front page is a form with one field, to enter a long url into:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type='url' name='url' placeholder='Enter URL to be shortened'>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The form posts to the same front page and the code for posting to '/' is this:

```
post '/' do
    #Makes variable of POSTed url.
    @long = params[:url]
    loop do
            #makes random six letter hash
        @rand = (0...6).map{(65+rand(26)).chr}.join.downcase
            #don't generate another one if it isn't found in the database
        break if Short.first(id: "#{@rand}").nil?
    end
    #saves url and hash to database
    @input = Short.create(url: @long, id: @rand)
    #displays link with hash to be copied into browser address bar
    "http://192.168.1.3:999/"+@rand

end
```

The problem is that when I submit the form, it doesn't return the `http://192.168.1.3:999/...` or anything I put after the `@input=Short.create(...` line. It doesn't return any errors, even when `raise_on_save_failure` is true. If I comment that line out, it works fine (except when trying to use the shortened url).

EDIT: When I change the code to allow non-urls, it functions perfectly normally. It only breaks with the exact url format.

Comment: Does the `Short` instance get created?

Comment: @iain I'm not sure. How can I check that?

Comment: `create` will add the data to the database. Have a look in the database - which one are you using?

Comment: Open the sqlite console by typing `sqlite3 path/to/database/file` and then `select * from shorts;` (or something similar) to get it to show you what's in the database. If you see the data, then it's definitely gone in.

Comment: Its a ruby gem so I can't open the console

Comment: The only way the gem works is if you have Sqlite installed, which means you'll have a console.

Comment: when I enter the `sqlite3` command, it says `-bash: sqlite3: command not found
`

Comment: That's a good indication of what might be the problem… make sure you've got Sqlite installed, and put up a list of the gems you've installed too.

Comment: I know that I have SQLite and that it works because I've used it with other projects quite recently.

Comment: Ok, but you don't have a console and you have a problem related to calling a database library that doesn't throw an error in the calling code… If it was me, I wouldn't be as confident in saying "I know that it works" ;)